# Forked execvp does not return, parent waits indefinitely

Tags: c, fork, pipe, wait, execvp

Code with some comments:
http://pastebin.com/nrXayHx5

I'm executing the command "du" repeatedly on a lot of files and directories, it works for a lot of my input but there's one particular directory that doesn't, i checked which one it was and the string is well-formed. I've noticed that the output of executing du with that directory is particularly long, might that be the reason for execvp not to return? maybe the pipe is full?

I appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: If a process attempts to write to a full pipe (see below), then write(2) blocks until sufficient data has been read from the pipe to allow the write to complete. Since Linux 2.6.11, the pipe capacity is 65536 bytes. I doubt the output has 65536 bytes.. but the problem is probably that write is blocking.

Comment: execvp is writing to a full pipe and blocks i checked pipe size with "ulimit -a" and its 4096 bytes, that's the problem.